# C#,Input string was not in a correct format.

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is wrong with my code?
there is an error "Input string was not in a correct format." , i cant seem to get that p

```
protected void bearer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["main"].ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();

    string insertquery = @"insert into verlog(bearerid,txndate,sendep,recdep,status) 
                                values(@bearer,@txndate,@depsend,@deprec,@status)";
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(insertquery, connection);
    string query2 = "select @@Identity";

    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bearer", bearer.Text);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depsend", drpSender.Text);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deprec", drpRec.Text);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Pending");
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txndate", Label1.Text);
    query.ExecuteNonQuery();
    query.CommandText = query2;

    object sample = query.ExecuteScalar();
    //Label2.Text = txnid.ToString();
    connection.Close();
   // Label2.Text = myCounter.ToString();
   // bearer.Text = bearer.Text.Trim();
}
```

Comment: when converting string to int fails this error occurs.. because string is not a valid number...

Comment: put your db table column datatypes here then we can help you , this error occurs when you are trying to insert different datatype values to table

Answer (score 3):

Is the `txtDate` field in the DB a `DateTime` field? If so, you are trying to pass a `String` to this field instead of a `DateTime` object.

```
 query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txndate", Label1.Text);
```

You should convert the contents of the `Label1` textbox to a `DateTime` object and then try and insert it.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Label1.Text);
```

Here is a link to the MSDN page on how to convert a String to a DateTime. This page shows how you can specify the expected input format of the string you are trying to parse using the `CultureInfo` object.

[How to: Convert a String to a DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx)

You should also check the other DB field types as well to ensure they are all `String` types - if not, you may need to convert some of the other fields  before trying to save data to DB

Comment: how can we ensure label is a valid date time ? i think it may be a string

Comment: Correct, I would add also the fact that the OP should use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() and execute just one call to the database joining the SELECT to the previous query and call ExecuteScalar

Comment: bearerid seems to be identity field

Comment: it still says input string was not in correct format , but when i check the db , the values i inputted where in the database.

Comment: Can you post your updated code along with the sample data you are trying to save to the DB. Can you also provide the DB table schema as well so we can see the column types. Finally can you post the full exception that is thrown and the exact line that is occurs on.